# Cellular Modem not Responding

Tags: minicom

I am trying to connect to my cellular modem on Linux.  I connect it through USB and the device appears as /dev/ttyUSB0.  Using minicom, I set the port and baud rate then connect to the device.  However, when I connect I get a weird output.
[image]

I turned on echo in minicom (crtl+a e) and when I try to enter a newline, this output just repeats. I also cannot get a response when issuing AT Commands.

What does this output mean?  Any other suggestions on what I can test?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to give me more information to help you, here I leave what I need:

- When you connect the USB modem to the PC, open the console and type: `dmesg | grep tty`. Could you let me know the answer? This is to verify where the modem was connected, I currently have one and it connects as **/dev/ttyACM0**
- Are you sure you're using the *right speed* (baudios)? This problem seems typical of a poorly chosen *speed*.
- I check that when using the Minicom instead of entering the program and then configure parameters it is preferable to access it directly with the parameters already offered, for example: 
  `minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 9600` Being the -D for "*device*" and -b for "*speed*" in (baudios)

Comment: I tired the suggestion you have made still had no luck.  I doubled checked the datasheet and found the USB is used for firmware updates, not AT commands. Should have checked prior.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Anyway, the modem that I use is the Keyestudio SIM900 GSM-GPRS shield for Arduino, if I can help you with this (I love those things) just ask me for help :-) Greetings!